# Features - Will I lose work if I decide to remove a feature from my dev site

Tags: 7, features

I have a feature on my site that covers several content types and views.  I want to change the configuration of my feature, but I am afraid that I will lose the work that I have done.  I recently learned that, when you remove a feature, it reverts that database back to the state it was in before the feature was added (for the configurations that the feature covers.)  Does this happen to the configurations on a site that a feature has be created to include, or configurations on a site that a feature has been used to add?  In other words, will removing a feature that I created on my development site erase all of the configurations that I just changed (which are included in that feature?)

Please note that this post is referring to a Development site (where features are created) and not a live site (where features are employed.)

Comment: Sounds to me like you should go ahead and make your configuration changes then _recreate_ your feature. No need to remove it or disable it.

Comment: Will everything work out if I remove a module that is covered by a feature?